# Cygwin Shell: $ make ex1 returns: "The system cannot find the specified file" on Windows 7

Tags: c, windows, shell, cygwin

I'm following the steps of the online book: "Learn C The Hard Way", and since I'm using Windows 7, I've installed Cygwin to use the Linux commands. But I'm facing a problem just on the first exercise of the book. I'm supposed to put the following command on the shell:

```
$ make ex1
```

After creating a ex1.c file on the folder. The command should give me:

```
cc     ex1.c   -o ex1
```

But instead, I'm getting the following message:

```
$ make ex1
cc     ex1.c   -o ex1
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cc ex1.c -o ex1, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the specified file.
make: *** [ex1] Error 2
```

What's wrong?

Comment: It would be diagnostic to run this command `cc -v` from a Cygwin prompt, and report the results.

Comment: Did you try running the command you expected "make" to run??? i.e.:        cc ex1.c -o ex1 .... Did that succeed...??? if not, you may need to install "gcc" in Cygwin...

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should know that you should be running the command in the same directory where the file is. In cygwin, first you will have to locate to the folder in which the file is present, then you can run these make commands. Better since you are using Windows. You should better use any other windows based client for C. But if I were at your place. I would have installed a virtual Linux environment on my local windows computer and would have worked on that. You should try that once. Linux Terminal gives a lot of power to the developer. There are a lot of things which you can do on a terminal which is not supported by cygwin. For compiling C programs on Cygwin, I believe you should check if it supports compiler commands or not. :)

Comment: They're on the same directory, I'm sure. How should I proceed installing a Virtual Environment? I'm really newbie with Linux/Unix.

Comment: Cygwin and your file need not be in the same directory. If you open cygwin, type in 'pwd', you will get the directory in which you are. You will have to use linux 'cd' command to get to the directory in which your C file is. For linux stuff, you should get a Virtual Environment Software e.g. Virtual Box. You will also need a linux ISO file for setting up your local virtual machine. You can easily google it. Linux is a great thing to start with. You can download Ubuntu Desktop edition from its website. The file will be in .iso format. That you can use in your virtualbox to set up a virtual env.

Answer (score 0):

Make is reporting that it can not find cc.
cc is a link to gcc, and it belongs to gcc-core.

```
$ cygcheck -f /usr/bin/cc  
gcc-core-5.4.0-1
```

To verify if the package is correctly installed

```
$ cygcheck -c gcc-core
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
gcc-core             5.4.0-1        OK
```

If, as likely, the package is missing, you need to install it with the cygwin setup.